# How to migrate a DataBase created in Visual Studio C# to a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to transfer/connect my database that I created in Visual Studio C# to SQL Server Management Studio 2016. I'm developing Hotel Management Software and my database is relative short and I don't have the time to create a new one because of all the code included in my program related to the database. I only have one DataSet and three tables. I'm using Windows Authentication but I need to use SQL Server Authentication but I don't know to do that.

I'll appreciate all the answers to my question.

Comment: Fabio, you question might get an answer quicker if you would describe the steps you took, and/or what documentation you have used. Can you go a bit more in detail, is there already data inside that should not get lost?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

First was getting acess to my DataBase.mdf file, so I changed my program path to a "PUBLIC" folder. My was in the USERS and I changed it to C:/ path.
Then in SQL Server Management, I entered with Windows Authentication first, then I went to "Databases" folder, right cliked, choose Attach, chosse Add, and I connected my Database.mdf in C:/ path.
After connection, I went to Security, right clicked Login and added a new login. Now I can acess with SQL Server Authentication.